# How to proper set DNS on home PC behind router?

Tags: router, dns

If I set DNS’ on router should I set the same DNS’ for LAN connections or these connection should use only router as DNS?

Is there some advantages one over other?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the router as DNS if you intend for any devices on your home network to "talk" to each other, this way if you want to copy a file from your laptop to your iPad the router should be able to resolve that request. If you use Google for DNS instead (8.8.8.8), Google can't resolve your iPad to your computer and vice versa.

Comment: @ Joshua Shourds: Okay, thanks. Are there some performance issues?

Comment: Adding any hop adds time, but usually less than a Millisecond per DNS request. So, no, no performance issue unless the router is really lousy.